# Trying to understand Wick setResponsePage for iframe display

Tags: java, iframe, wicket

My first page has links to files that are stored in a database. Clicking a link opens my second page, which displays the document in an `<iframe>`. I have tried three ways of calling the second page. One way fails to work and the other two are not secure: logout following by clicking back re-opens the page.

Files from the database are copied to **MyProject/web/** folder on the server. 
The `<iframe src=...>` attribute is replaced with the file path by the overridden `InlineFrame#onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag)`.

Method 1 fails to find the file. I would prefer to use this method as it is the most secure. First page

```
setResponsePage(DisplayResourcePage.class, params);
```

The second page should get the file from the database.

```
DisplayResourcePage(PageParameters parameters) {..}
```

Some diagnostics. The browser shows a 404 File Not Found error. I am not sure where it is looking for the file. `src` will be replaced. Can it be that the initial `src` still affects the location where the file is expected to be read from?

```
realPath: C:\Users\joe\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\MyProject
src before ./com.mycompany.shared.DisplayResourcePage?4-1.ILinkListener-pdfframe
```

Method 2 finds the file but is not secure. First page

```
setResponsePage(new DisplayResourcePage(params));
```

The second page gets the file from the database using the same constructor.

```
DisplayResourcePage(PageParameters parameters) {..}
```

Some diagnostics. `src` is the initial `<iframe src=...>` attribute. It is replaced by the file path in all cases.

```
realPath: C:\Users\joe\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\MyProject
src before ./page?7-1.ILinkListener-pdfframe
```

Method 3 finds the file but is not secure. First page

```
setResponsePage(new DisplayResourcePage(item.getModelObject()));
```

The second page gets the file from the database using a different constructor.

```
public DisplayResourcePage(EntityOtherResourceModel resourceModelItem) {..}
```

The diagnostics are the same as method 2.

Answer (score 0):

MyPage(AnyObject) is usually more secure than MyPage(PageParameters) because it creates non-bookmarkable url.

I think you should focus on why the page doesn't return error 403 (not authorized) after logout. To me you have some issue in the authentication logic of your application.

Another option could be that the page is saved in the browser cache and that's why it is loading after logout but by default Wicket sets "no-store" pragma for pages.

Comment: `setHeaders(WebResponse)` was already overridden. It is called during construction but not after the back button is pressed. Where can I watch messages being exchanged?

Comment: When using `MyPage(AnyObject)`, logout following by clicking the back button traps the page and show the SessionError page when Chrome Developer Tools are open but not when they are closed. I do not understand why.

Comment: I have managed to locate a specified file using Method 1. Unfortunately, the page gets re-loaded after clicking Logout and the back button.

Comment: Is it loaded from the browser cache or a new HTTP call is made for it ? The correct behavior is to make a new call and the server to return error 401.

Comment: It is loaded from the browser cache, despite my efforts to prevent it. Developer Tools does not show any messages and my server code is not called.